# cygwin bash tab completion for arguments fork failure

Tags: bash, cygwin, tab-completion

I have an odd problem with tab completion under cygwin's bash on my Win 7 installation. I get fork failures ('permission denied') under very specific circumstances..

Tab completion works fine for all commands.

Tab completion works fine for *arguments* of builtins and any cygwin-supplied program in /usr/bin, /usr/sbin, etc. (including .exe files as well as shell scripts)

Tab completion works fine for commands in my personal ~/bin directory.

However, whenever I attempt tab completion for an *argument* to one of my own shell scripts, I get a fork/permission denied error.

I've compared file permissions and ownerships of my shell scripts to those of cygwin-supplied shell scripts, and they are equivalent.

I've created a directory outside of the /cygwin/C hierarchy (named it /mybin) and copied my scripts into that directory. Then invoked the scripts directly (e.g., /mybin/gv n[TAB]) and the failure still occurs.

I've made sure the scripts have mode 775 and owned by me. I've made sure the directory in which the scripts exists is mode 775 and is also owned by me.

I haven't created anything in /usr/share/bash-completion (afaik, I shouldn't have to for argument-based filename completion). But I've not had issues with cygwin scripts without entries in /usr/share/bash-completion (e.g., /bin/zegrep is a shell script but has nothing under /usr/share/bash-completion)

I'm stumped at this point, but would like to resolve it since tab completion is such a vital feature.

Here's an example...

```
% gv n[TAB] 0 [main] bash 9308 fork: child -1 -CreateProcessW
failed for 'C:\Users\binaryb\cygwin\bin\bash.exe', errno 13 bash:
fork: Permission denied
```

.. in this example I was attempting to complete a filename (in current directory) by typing 'n[TAB]'. There is only one file starting with 'n' in my current directory.

I am running this under Win 7 (64 bit), with the following cygwin bash.exe version...

```
% uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-6.1 binaryb 2.10.0(0.325/5/3) 2018-02-02 15:16 x86_64 Cygwin

% bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem, but I'm not 100% sure. It seems to occur for scripts whose filenames are only 1 or 2 characters long. If I rename my script to, say, gvx, the problem goes away.

```
% gv n[TAB] 0 [main] bash 4556 fork: child -1 - CreateProcessW
failed for 'C:\Users\binaryb\cygwin\bin\bash.exe', 
errno 13 bash: fork: Permission denied

% mv ~/bin/gv ~/bin/gvx

% gvx n[TAB]
% gvx newfile.txt
```